# an unordered list background filled with 2 colors equally - CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to fill the background of an unordered list equally with black and white sharp colors. How-to? No gradients, just 2 colors filling each 50%, horizontally the background of the unordered list.

Thank you.

Comment: please consider marking my answer as the accepted answer, if it did solve your problem. This will signal other users, that this question needs no further attention. And it will highlight my answer, for future visitors of this question as a correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by using a color gradient with the appropriate stops. I have included a snippet. Though I am not 100% sure if that is indeed what you want. If not, please make your requirements a little clearer and post what you have already achieved/tried.

edit: sorry you said horizontally, I changed the snippet to acommodate that.

```css
ul.two-colors {
  color: lightblue;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 0%, black 50%, white 50%, white 100%);
}
div {
  background: grey;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="two-colors">
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```